# Object is set to null before persisting - ZF2/Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm relatively new to zend framework 2 and doctrine 2 so please bear with me.

I have two entities - Bills and Payments. I am trying to create a payment form so I can make payments to a single bill. The problem is that when I go to make a payment I get a nasty error

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Application\Entity\Payment::addBill() must be an instance of
>   Application\Entity\Bill, null given, called in
>   /var/www/zend/module/Bill/src/Bill/Controller/BillController.php

so I do a var dump on the `$bill_obj` and get this:

```
//VAR DUMP RESULTS
object(Application\Entity\Bill)[337]
  protected 'inputFilter' => null
  protected 'id' => int 5
  protected 'creditor' => string 'sdafddddddd' (length=11)
  protected 'type' => string '123fasdfsadfdd' (length=14)
```

`$bill_obj` is an instance of Bill. If I set `$bill_id` to `5` it works.

```
public function paymentAction()
{
    $bill_id  = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
    $bill_obj = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Application\Entity\Bill', $bill_id);
    var_dump($bill_obj);
    $form     = new PaymentForm();
    $request  = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->addBill($bill_obj);
        $form->setInputFilter($payment->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $payment->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($payment);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

            // Redirect to list of bills
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('bill');
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

And this is Payment Entity:

```
class Payment implements InputFilterAwareInterface 
{
protected $inputFilter;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bill", inversedBy="id")
 */
protected $bill;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float")
 */
protected $amount;

/**
 * Magic getter to expose protected properties.
 *
 * @param string $property
 * @return mixed
 */
```

Bill Entity:

```
class Bill implements InputFilterAwareInterface 
{
protected $inputFilter;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $creditor;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $type;
```

Comment: The var dump is without setting `$bill_id` manually?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work-around. I set a hidden field with the bill id as the value and use that in the find method. I would still like to know why I couldn't get the id from the route. If anybody knows please comment. Thanks!

```
public function paymentAction()
{

    $bill_id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id');

    $form = new PaymentForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $data = $request->getPost();
        $payment = new Payment();
        $bill_obj = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Application\Entity\Bill', $data['bill_id']);
        $payment->addBill($bill_obj);
        $form->setInputFilter($payment->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $payment->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($payment);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

            // Redirect to list of bills
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('bill');
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form, 'id' => $bill_id);
}
```